# Can't figure out associations in Rails_Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-admin

I have two models like so:

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sex
  attr_accessible :name
end

class Sex < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description
  has_many :kids
end
```

But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get the association to show up in the admin. When I go to edit a kid, I see a label for sex, but there is no dropdown, no hint whatsoever that RailsAdmin sees the association. It just shows the label name, a blank space and the word "optional" below.

I've searched through the dox over and over and over, yet I can't find a solution. I'm a noob, so it's possible I looked right over it and should be subject to ridicule.

I have not modified any other admin code.

Answer (score 8):

The relation should be accessible in Kid, try to add sex_id to accessible attributes.

`class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sex
  attr_accessible :name, :sex_id
end`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gaël Marziou, I figured out how to 'connect' with the intermediate *model* (the one used with has_many :through... association) like so:

```
class CategoryPets < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :pet

  attr_accessible :category_id, :pet_id
end
```